# If $f$ and $g$ are integrable then is $\max\{f,g\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is the pointwise maximum of two Riemann integrable functions Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72844/is-the-pointwise-maximum-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions-riemann-integrable)

Let $f$ and $g$ be two integrable real functions. Is this leads that $\max\{f,g\}$ is integrable too?

Any proof?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean Riemann integrable, it was answered in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72844/is-the-pointwise-maximum-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions-riemann-integrable

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate, but I might be mistaken. The OP has not clarified whether Riemann or Lebesgue integration is intended. [Future voters: Please wait for some clarification from the OP.]

Answer (score 19):

$\max (f,g) = (f+g + |f-g|)/2$, so in the Lebesgue theory max(f,g) is integrable because linear combinations and absolute values of integrable functions are integrable.

Comment: Better to say: Because of this identity, it suffices to prove the special case: If $f$ is integrable, then $|f|$ is integrable.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, I don't quite understand the sufficiency. Can you explain a bit why the special case would lead to the identity. (For those who may not know how to prove the special case, here is a proof of it. If $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable, then $\lvert f \rvert$ is integrable by definition. If $f$ is Riemann-integrable, then $f$ is bounded and so $\lvert f \rvert$ is integrable(since Riemann integrals are defined over bounded intervals). )

Answer (score 13):

$$
|\max(f,g)|\leqslant\max(|f|,|g|)\leqslant|f|+|g|
$$

Comment: For full credit, needs more explanation.

Comment: GEdgar, thanks for your interest but I like it as is. Kind of similar to the point @Srivatsan made in a comment to the post, if you like. (What do you call *full credit*, by the way?)