# If f(x) is integrable on [a,b], let g(x)=min(f(x),10). Is g(x) integrable on [a,b]? (Prove or find a counterexample.)

Tags: calculus

Any hint? I am thinking about the trignometric function as a counterexample, but I still cannot have a clue.

Comment: Please see this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86031/if-f-and-g-integrable-then-max-f-g-is.

Comment: If the integrals are in Lebesgue sense then the answer is YES.